# wordpress recent posts show thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, widget, thumbnails, posts

How can I show either a small thumbnail of a image or featured image, from each post In my recent posts custom widget

Here's my code:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $root . 'blog/wp-load.php');

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 3
));

?>

<h3 class="divider">Recent Blog Posts</h3>
<ul class="listing">
<?php foreach($recent_posts as $post) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
    <div><?php echo $post['post_title'] ?></div></a></li>
<?php } ?>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `get_the_post_thumbnail`

Usage:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

Integrated with your code:

```
<?php foreach($recent_posts as $post) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post['ID']) ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post['ID'], 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <div><?php echo $post['post_title'] ?></div>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Note:** To enable Post Thumbnails, the current theme must include [`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails) in its functions.php file. See also [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

**Source(s)**

[Function Reference/get the post thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

**See also**

[Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)
[Function Reference/add theme support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support)

Answer (score -1):

In your current installed theme, if you are making any changes to the PHP files, it will get replaced if there are any updates done to the theme. To avoid, this, create a child theme and make updates to those php files.

Thr below blog also explains in details on how to add Thumbnail to Recent post widget.

[Blog on how to Add Thumbnail to Recent posts](http://officetricks.com/display-recent-posts-with-thumbnails-without-plugins/)

Hope this helps.